# iOS swift custom UICollectionView with Custom Cell does not call didSelectItem

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, collectionview

I got some issues with the following code: I created a custom Cell with a Custom UICollectionView class. I used Xib files instead of the storyboard.
It never calls the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method but why? I am really desperate :'(.

```
    import UIKit

class CustomCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var refreshControl : UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
        self.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout

        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refreshData:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.addSubview(refreshControl)

        self.userInteractionEnabled = true


        self.registerClass(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "outfit")
        self.registerNib(UINib(nibName: layoutHelper.getCellXibName("CustomCollectionViewCell"), bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "outfit")

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    }

    //
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource - Methods
    //

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell : CustomCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("outfit", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.label.text = "Outfit #" + String(indexPath.row)
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://placehold.it/177x370")
        cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, completed: nil)
        return cell
    }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("at index path %i", indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you subclassed the `UICollectionView` itself rather than the controller of the view the collection view in nested in?

Comment: Yes, because in the future that view is a lot more than just the collection view. Besides that I am reusing the collection view multiple times in the app.

Comment: Does it not call didSelectItemAtIndexPath no matter where you touch the cell? The touch won't work over the image view unless you've set its userInteractionEnabled property to YES. BTW, there's no need to register both the class and the nib. If your cell is made in a xib file, then you only need to register the nib.

Comment: Try this `self.collectionView.delegate = self` and `self.collectionView.dataSource = self`

Comment: UserInterActionEnabled is setted to YES. Thank u for the tip with nib register.

Comment: The delegate and datasource is setted to self in the init method.

Comment: @ilyas-hallak do u find the right answer?